# AppleScript dialog at specific emplacement

Tags: applescript, dialog

is there a way to run an AppleScript dialog as a specific emplacement?
like you would do for an app using

```
tell application "System Events"
    set position of first window of application process "Slack" to {5724, 0, 6967, 647}
end tell
```

the dialog example:

```
set myDialog to {"Demo", "Demo two", "Demo Trois"}
set selectedResolution to choose from list myDialog with title "title here" with prompt "message here" default items "Deny Abuse"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with basic *vanilla* **AppleScript** as the `choose from list` *command* creates a *modal dialog window* and further processing of the *script* is on hold until you respond to.

There *may* be a way with **AppleScriptObjC** to create the *dialog window* programmatically and tell it where to appear on the screen, but that is not my area of expertise.

Comment: thank you that's answer my question.